# Installation error with checkinstall

Tags: compiling

after solving all the dependencies (./configure, make , sudo checkinstall )terminal reports. Please help me compile my first source package in Ubuntu. I'm building the package in `/usr/local/src` on 10.10 netbook edition. What do I do because I know I'm so close to my goal. Thanks in advance

[image: Installation results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the directory `/usr/local/share/icons` is missing. Create it by running:

```
sudo install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/icons
```

Such an installation rule should be added to the Makefile by the developers of klavaro.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage your question is much better suited for a Klavaro mailing list. You're not doing anything Ubuntu specific: you're installing a program from source on linux. Unless I misunderstand you..

I see that it's having trouble creating a directory. Maybe this is permissions related. Try running your commands again with `sudo`.